# wget: unable to resolve host address 'terraria.org'

Tags: wget, ubuntu-server

I am very unfamiliarized with linux and I have a spare pc lying around, I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS. It's all connected to the internet and I have verified that, but when I run:
`terraria@mc-ubuntu:~$ wget https://terraria.org/api/download/pc-dedicated-server/terraria-server-1436.zip -O server.zip`
all that it gives me is this that of which I have no clue what to do:
`wget: unable to resolve host address 'terraria.org'`
I need help, and yes I have tried in root, same output.

Answer (score 0):

I checked if mentioned file exists using `--spider` option

```
wget --spider https://terraria.org/api/download/pc-dedicated-server/terraria-server-1436.zip
```

output

```
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2022-06-28 10:19:47--  https://terraria.org/api/download/pc-dedicated-server/terraria-server-1436.zip
Resolving terraria.org (terraria.org)... 188.114.96.13, 188.114.97.13
Connecting to terraria.org (terraria.org)|188.114.96.13|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 43392536 (41M) [application/zip]
Remote file exists.
```

so URL you have used seems to be correct, therefore I suspect issue with DNS lookup. `wget` is unable to find IP address corresponding to `terraria.org`. You need to add some `nameserver` aware of `terraria.org` to `/etc/resolv.conf` file, I suggest trying Google one that is add following line

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

to `/etc/resolv.conf` then write if it did help (I do not have ability to test that)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and your help! Absolute Legend :D!